# ForEach loop to iterate through ArrayList got from external Class

Tags: java, database, loops, jsp, arraylist

I've got two classes: `Subject` and `Subjects`. `Subject` stores data containing data found in a database (id, name and abbreviation). `Subjects` makes a database connection and returns an ArrayList containing `Subject`s.

Subject.java:

```
public class Subject {

   public int id;
   public String subjectName;
   public String subjectAbbr;

 //and some getters and setters

}
```

Subjects.java:

```
public class Subjects {

    public ArrayList getAllFromSubject() throws SQLException {

        Database DB = new Database();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM `subject`;";
        //DB.exequteQuery returns a ResultSet with the data from the query.
        ResultSet result = DB.executeQuery(query);

        ArrayList<Subject> output = new ArrayList();

        while (result.next()) {

            Subject subject = new Subject();

            subject.setId(result.getInt("id"));
            subject.setSubjectName(result.getString("subjectname"));
            subject.setSubjectAbbr(result.getString("subjectabbr"));

            output.add(subject);

        }

        DB.closeExistingConnection();

        return output;

    }

}
```

I've got `signup.jsp`, containing a dropdown select menu and I want the user be able to choose from the abbrevations found in the database. So I can call `Subjects.getAllFromSubject()` and I get an ArrayList containing a number of `Subject`s. I'd like to display all those `Subject`s abbrevations in a `<select>`-menu. This can be done by a forEach loop, but I'm am not sure how to do that and how to get the abbrevation from a `Subject`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated: you want to read about **not** using raw types with generics. For example, a much better return type for your method would look like : `public List<Subject> getAllFromSubject()` or something alike. Really, that are **important** basics; and unless you understand such things, you better stay away from talking to databases or other advanced topics.

Comment: Do you use any framework with your jsp ?

Comment: +ChristosLoupasdakis my jsp is nothing more than a file with HTML and some Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help:

index.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="jvanamerongen.example.Subjects"%>
<%@page import="jvanamerongen.example.Subject"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <% Subjects list = new Subjects(); %>
        <select>
            <% for(Subject s : list.getAllFromSubject()) { %>
                <option value="<% out.print(s.getId()); %>"><% out.print(s.getSubjectAbbr()); %></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try this in a minute, but now you're accessing `subject.id` directly, is it possible to just use a getter?

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but unfortunately your code doesn't seem to work. I added the line <%@page import="business.*"%> to include both classes, but without success

Comment: <%@page import="business.Subjects"%>
<%
        Subjects  obj = new Subjects();
%>

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that this doesn't solve the problem either. My IDE does say that `obj` is not used.

Comment: What is your IDE?

Comment: My IDE is Netbeans 8.1

Comment: OK. I finally discover your problem. Solution edited!

Comment: Your solution does work, but only if the getAllFromSubject() looks like this: `public ArrayList<Subject> getAllFromSubject() {}`, without the diamond operators it does not work.